# transition from asyncore to asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, macos-sierra, python-asyncio, asyncore

I am currently trying to transition from `asyncore` to `asyncio` since I am porting some old code from **python 27** to **python 35**. But I am not very familiar yet with both.

Here is a condensed version of the problematic part:

```
import socket
import asyncore


mapDict = {}
fc = FeedbackController(port)
fc.start()

class FeedbackController(object):
     def __init__(self, port=None):       
                self.ipcchannel = IPCConnectionHandler(self, theMap=mapDict)
                self.udpconnectionhandler = UDPDispatcher(self, theMap=mapDict)


    def start(self):
                asyncore.loop(timeout=60.0,map=theMap)

    …

class UDPDispatcher(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, theMap):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, map=theMap)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.bind((LOCALHOST, FC_PORT))

class IPCConnectionHandler(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self,theMap=None):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, map=theMap)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.bind((LOCALHOST, IPC_PORT))
        self.listen(5)
```

At the moment, I am running on Macos Sierra and it crashes when the `asyncore.loop` is called

Any help on how to transition would be great

Comment: Same problem for me.